# Is there a way to temporarily allow popups in Safari 6 without going into Preferences?

Tags: safari

If I know I'm about to click on a link that will pop up a window that I want, is there a modifier key or anything I can do to temporarily allow the popup to appear, without going into Safari's preferences window, unchecking the box, opening the popup, then checking the box again (and getting the same warning every single time)?

Answer (score 2):

At least in Safari 5.1.7 it's under Safari menu

[image]

Comment: In Safari 6, it's not anymore. It's in the preferences window.

Comment: That's a pity. Won't cmd+click work as just opening the same link not in a window but in a new tab?

Comment: In this case, the particular page causing me an issue wasn't a link at all, it was triggered by the onchange event of a SELECT. (I think if it had been a link, Safari would have been smart enough not to block it.) I tried holding down Command while changing the SELECT, but that didn't unblock the popup.

Comment: Or yes I see. I would just use other browser for that site.